# vscode `ctrl + tab` needs confirmation first

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

when I press `ctrl + tab` it doesn't move the file right away but rather shows a list of all open files

I need the default behavior where it takes me right away to the last opened file without having to press enter

PS: if this helps in any way I'm using Linux Mint (LMDE 4 (debbie) x86_64)

Comment: Aybak3K, did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: It turns out extension "keyboard macro beta" was causing this behaviour.

Comment: thank you but I have no way of testing that rn as I switched to Ubuntu

Comment: Can confirm. Disabling the "keyboard macro beta" extension solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, just release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. That will take you to the last file you were in.

For instance, if you're in `FileA` and you have `FileB` and `FileC` open and you were last in `FileC`, <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> shows the list, and when you release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, you're taken to `FileC`. Do it again (releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) and you'll be back in `FileA`.

Comment: *(Sorry, there was a typo above: "...you're taking to `FileB`..." should be "...you're taken to `FileC`" [and it is, if you hit refresh].)*

Comment: And Hi! from a fellow Mint user. :-)

Comment: that's what I do! even though I release `ctrl` it just freezes to the list unless I press enter<br>and I'm very happy to meet  you too:)

Comment: Well that's very odd. It doesn't do that for me (using Cinnamon, FWIW). It behaves the same way it does on Windows (I don't use OSX), which is what I describe above. Odd!

Comment: neither did it when I was working on ubuntu. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Check your keyboard shortcuts. Find the command:

```
workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInEditorPicker
```

By default it is set to Ctrl-Tab, if yours is not, set it that keybinding by clicking on the pencil icon to the left of the command on hover and enter Ctrl-Tab into the dialog box.

That command should also be using the when clauses: inEditorsPicker && inQuickOpen

Comment: thanks but neither is the problem i described

Comment: As you are using linux, may be https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26176 can help you.

Comment: Also, you can try with my modified answer.

Comment: ah I didn take notice.
it's set to `ctrl` `tab` and have the exact clauses described..